# Dropdown shows primary keys instead of the name in ASP.NET core and Razor

Tags: c#, html, linq, asp.net-core, razor

I am working with `viewbag` in C# and I want to show some colors in a `<select>` tag on my HTML page.

This is my model in c#

```
public class CoreColorGroup
{
   [Key]
   public long CORECOLORGROUPID { get; set; }

   [MaxLength(100)]
   public string NAME { get; set; }
}
```

In my **Controller** I query the viewbag like this:

```
ViewBag.colorlist = await _context
                            .DbSet<CoreColorGroup>()
                            .Query.OrderBy(x => x.CORECOLORGROUPID)
                            .Select(x => new SelectListItem(x.CORECOLORGROUPID.ToString(), x.NAME))
                            .ToListAsync();
```

The viewbag is working good I debug my application and I get the colors via the controller.

And this is my select tag:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="CoreColorGroup" class="control-label"></label>
    <select asp-for="CORECOLORGROUPID" asp-items="@ViewBag.colorlist" class="form-control"></select>
</div>
```

When I run the application the dropdown contains the **primary keys** instead of the **name** of the colors.

How can I show the **colors names** instead of the **primary keys**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not initialising `SelectListItem` correctly, `SelectListItem` doesn't have a [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.selectlistitem?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) that takes 2 arguments.

Specify the `Value` and `Text` properties and use the object initialiser syntax when creating `SelectListItem`:

```
.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x.NAME, Value = x.CORECOLORGROUPID.ToString()})
```